# How to pass Value to HashSet of a Model from View C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my view I am trying to fill up the model by using Razor html.hidden.
the model has to properties the first one is regular list and I do a regular for loop and .hidden works there without any problem , but I cant do the same thing with foreach

```
foreach (var dup in Model.DuplicateNum)
            {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h1 style="color:red">@dup</h1>*
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => @dup)
                </td>
            </tr>
            }
```

so the `DuplicateNum` is a `HashSet`. when i run that code I the `Model.DuplicateNum` is Null. How can I fill up a `HashSet` using `Razor`.
Here is how I am doing passing values from my view to Model

The code below List works and passes the values to one of the properties in my model, the other property is not getting filed up ..

```
int subjectsCount = Model.AssignedNumbers.Count();
for (int item = 0; item < subjectsCount; item++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Model.AssignedNumbers[item]


                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.AssignedNumbers[item])


                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
```

Comment: Sorry ! I am having trouble understanding your problem. You are getting NULL in your view ? Did you load that property from your action method ?

Comment: @Shyju thanks for the reply, so I have a View that has results as HTML. That HTML renders the same view but in order for me to pass those information back to the Same Model I am using Razor . I will add the other section on how I am filling up my other list and pass the values one by one

Comment: what is the type of DuplicateNum?

Comment: @Lukos HashSet public HashSet<String> DuplicateNum { get; set; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start, your `HiddenFor` looks wrong. `@Html.HiddenFor(x => @dup)` means that in the context of your model, create a hidden with the value of your dup. The model binder works with names and values so I don't see how that would bind anything to the property `DuplicateNum`.

You can either specify the names yourself and use `@Html.Hidden("DuplicateNum", dup)` which I think should work or you might be able to use `HiddenFor()` in some way but it will need to be bound to the correct property (`DuplicateNum`) but still know which item to display so I don't know how to do that.

You could also use pure html and just render something like `<input type="hidden" name="DuplicateNum" value="@dup"/>` which I have used in one of my views and that also binds in a more manual and understandable way!

Comment: Thank you so much , great information . I am new to C# and razor, do you know where I can read more about @Html... and different type of stuff I can use that with like Hiddenfor() or Hidden() and what kind of values goes in there

Comment: I don't know much off the top of my head, there is SOOO much around and some of it is old. The best thing to remember is that the HtmlHelper only produces pure HTML at the end of the day and just uses names and values to bind things. In the worst case, make a pretend view with some basic model binding and see what happens when you run it, you'll see how it binds to different kinds of properties etc.

Comment: So the ...For() methods are just a way to make sure the correct names and types are produced without you having to type them, they aren't some magic superglue that is required for every type of binding! You can bind with pure HTML and hard-coded text or the HtmlHelper methods.